# Missing front of cabinet drawer, need to sell my house

Tags: cabinets, drawers

One of the drawer front panels for a kitchen cabinet broke a while ago and I need to somehow get it replaced but I don't know where to look or who I should contact.  I don't have the panel anymore at all.  The main issue is that I am trying to sell my house so I need to get it repaired somehow.  The panel above it is the same, so i can take that panel off and take it somewhere to get replicated somehow, i just dont know where to take it and if its possible due to the color.  Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do for this?

[image: Missing cabinet panel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you can identify the manufacturer. Frequently the manufacturer will have some sort of marking on the side of the drawer boxes. Pull out some of the drawers and see if you find anything indicating who built them.

It's also common for manufacturers to leave a label somewhere in the sink base cabinet. Look on the door or inside the cabinet to see if you find anything. The label will typically indicate the style and finish.

As beazors mentioned it looks like you're also missing the front of the drawer box and you're probably better off getting a whole drawer assembly if possible.

Comment: Using your instructions i was able to find some labeling for the manufacturer and get a hold of them.  Currently working with them for a replacement.  Thanks!

Comment: @RaymondHolguin glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

The major home centers, Lowes, Home Depot, etc can typically order items such as this custom made. If the cabinet was originally a "stock" size cabinet from such a place, it should be easy to get a replacement. You may or may not be able to find a match to the finish, though. I would hesitate to spend a lot on a really good replacement as a merely adequate replacement would probably fill your need and not be an issue for the next owner. Bring the existing drawer in, and possibly one of the others, as a sample. If two drawers are the same, bring the completed one with you and ask for a copy of that. Be sure to measure the width, depth, and height where the drawer will go.

Alternatively, you could look locally in the yellow pages or google maps for custom cabinet shops. Some of the smaller ones may pick up any work they can get and would most likely be able to stain match what you have already. You'll pay more though, shop time in a good cabinet shop can be $60 to $100 or more, and for a drawer like that, they might charge you for several hours of work including the staining/finishing.

Answer (score 1):

There are many websites online that sell drawer faces and cabinet doors for re-facing, when people change the look of their kitchens without changing out the actual cabinet boxes. If you can find out what the finish/company is, along with measurements, you may be able to get a close enough match. I think most places charge around $20 per square foot, so a small drawer front shouldn't be too expensive.

EDIT: It looks like you're also missing the front of the drawer box. Typically drawers have two layers at the front, (1) the front of the drawer box and (2) the decorative outer front. If you can't DIY that yourself, you could also order a new drawer box online.

Comment: Actually, the drawer box is attached to the front panel, at least on all of the other drawers.  But good to know in case the replacement I get doesn't have that same configuration.